# Metamask PW recovery

Tags: passwords, metamask, password-recovery

I have lost the password to my Metamask wallet. The recovery phrase I have does not work either (maybe I typed it wrongly) so the ideas is to try and recover the PW. I partially remember the PW and I was thinking to try to autogenerate different variations of it and then try to feed it onto on my Metamask. I was suggested John the ripper? any other ideas? anyone who could help with the task?

Thanks!

I tried using John the Ripper to generate my PW but I am lost in the code steps.